# SQL & Multiple tables and outputting data but also where data does not exist

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables within my data base:

- User Table
- Documents Table
- User-ReadDoc Table (Many-to-Many)

At the moment when I select the data from the two tables it will only display what document the user has read. I want to output the full list of documents but output if the user has or hasnt read the document.

In the "User-ReadDoc" table there is a column that specifies this.

Sudo Code Example

```
SELECT * FROM Documents, User-ReadDoc
```

It will just display rows saying who has read the document I just want a list so if that data is not there just truent it and place a "null" or a "0"

BTW I'm using SQL Server 2005...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT JOIN is the way to go

```
SELECT * FROM Documents d LEFT JOIN User-ReadDoc ud ON d.DocID = ud.DocID
```

plus you should select needed fields only.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Tristian and welcome to Stack Overflow.

What you are looking for is an left outer join.  To include all items from table A and only those items from table B where they match.

> A LEFT OUTER JOIN is one of the JOIN operations that allow you to specify a join clause. It preserves the unmatched rows from the first (left) table, joining them with a NULL row in the shape of the second (right) table. [source](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html)

So in your example it would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Documents D 
LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Read_Docs U
ON D.ID = U.ID
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I also found another way with a UNION join. Good stuff thanks for the quick feed back :)

Comment: Great.  If this answer is closed make sure to mark this response with a checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the actual fields, but it sounds to me that you need a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick. Uses a CROSS JOIN to give every combination of User and Document, then a LEFT JOIN to User-ReadDoc to see if that user has read that document or not.

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN r.documentid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasRead
FROM User u
    CROSS JOIN Documents d
    LEFT JOIN [User-ReadDoc] r ON u.userid = r.userid 
        AND d.documentid = r.documentid
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear as to whether you want total count of reads on each document, or total count of reads per user per document.

This will give you total count of reads per document.

```
SELECT DD.*, ISNULL(XX.Reads, 0)
FROM   [Documents] DD
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(1) Reads
                    FROM [User-ReadDoc] RR
                    WHERE RR.DocKey = DD.DocKey) XX
```

This will give you total count of reads by document and user.

```
SELECT UU.UserKey, DD.*, ISNULL(XX.Reads, 0)
FROM   [User] UU
       CROSS JOIN [Documents] DD
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(1) Reads
                    FROM [User-ReadDoc] RR
                    WHERE RR.DocKey = DD.DocKey AND RR.UserKey = UU.UserKey) XX
```

And, if you just want for one user:

```
DECLARE @userKey INT

SELECT UU.UserKey, DD.*, ISNULL(XX.Reads, 0)
FROM   [Documents] DD
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(1) Reads
                    FROM [User-ReadDoc] RR
                    WHERE RR.DocKey = DD.DocKey AND RR.UserKey = @userKey) XX
```